# resize2fs failed to find disk

Tags: debian, disk, resize2fs

I'm trying to resize my disk that's on google cloud from 1TB to 2 TB. I resized the disk space in google's console as instructed and:

```
df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          95G  7.1G   88G   8% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        95G  7.1G   88G   8% /etc/hosts
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdg        984G  381G  554G  41% /var/lib/data
tmpfs            16G   12K   16G   1% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/firmware
```

and:

```
lsblk

NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0  100G  0 disk
|-sda1    8:1    0 95.9G  0 part /etc/hosts
|-sda2    8:2    0   16M  0 part
|-sda3    8:3    0    2G  0 part
|-sda4    8:4    0   16M  0 part
|-sda5    8:5    0    2G  0 part
|-sda6    8:6    0  512B  0 part
|-sda7    8:7    0  512B  0 part
|-sda8    8:8    0   16M  0 part
|-sda9    8:9    0  512B  0 part
|-sda10   8:10   0  512B  0 part
|-sda11   8:11   0    8M  0 part
`-sda12   8:12   0   32M  0 part
sdb       8:16   0    2G  0 disk
sdc       8:32   0    8G  0 disk
sdd       8:48   0   10G  0 disk
sde       8:64   0 1000G  0 disk
sdf       8:80   0   10G  0 disk
sdg       8:96   0    2T  0 disk /var/lib/data
```

now i tried to use resize2fs to resize and got:

```
resize2fs /dev/sdg

resize2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
open: No such file or directory while opening /dev/sdg
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to perform this from inside a container, you'll get the same error, and the `/dev/` directory will not show the virtual device.

In this case, log into the host node [ec2/compute/??] and perform the `resize2fs`